# Get all results from NLTK concordance

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, python-3.4

I'm using NLTK to find the concordance of a word, but I don't know how to get all the results and put them in a `list` or `set`.

For example:

`text.concordance(word)`

prints just the first 25 results.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

```
text.concordance(lines=100)
```

---

From the code, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/text.py#L323:

```
def concordance(self, word, width=79, lines=25):
    """
    Print a concordance for ``word`` with the specified context window.
    Word matching is not case-sensitive.
    :seealso: ``ConcordanceIndex``
    """
    if '_concordance_index' not in self.__dict__:
        #print("Building index...")
        self._concordance_index = ConcordanceIndex(self.tokens,
                                                   key=lambda s:s.lower())

    self._concordance_index.print_concordance(word, width, lines)
```

Comment: `text.concordance_list(lines=100)` will return a `list`.

Comment: [text.concordance_list](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=concordance#nltk.text.Text.concordance_listt) could be used in combination with **join** to get a list of all word concordance.